# Como aumentar limite de memória de um processo?

Tags: ubuntu

Existe uma maneira de ilimitar a memória utilizada por um processo no Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar o comando

```
ulimit -v unlimited
```

antes de chamar o processo. Veja também se há alguma restrição no arquivo */etc/security/limits.conf* . Isso vai ilimitar o uso de memória virtual. Aparentemente não há como setar uma restrição para memória residente se você não estiver escrevendo o próprio código do programa.

Fonte: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32368/how-to-limit-application-memory-usage